# Is there a downside to make a .net dll com visible?

Tags: c#, .net, com

You can make your old COM apps use your .NET dlls by basically checking "[Register for COM Interop](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817248)" in the configurations window. What's the downside? (if there aren't any then why even have the option, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That option exists so that you can start debugging your [ComVisible] code right after building it.  Which has very little to do with "make your old COM apps use your .NET dlls".

It is not automatic because there are many practical cases where you don't want this done.  Because it requires VS to run elevated so it can write the registry keys.  Or because you don't want to register at all since you use a manifest instead.  Which is the preferable way, COM registration is quite brittle with rather serious DLL Hell problems and requires an installer to make it work on your user's machine.  And note the missing "Unregister for COM interop" option.  Tony Williams (the godfather of COM) first slide during a presentation about the registry said: "sorry, sorry, sorry, sorry, sorry, sorry..."

You might be sorry with just blindly turning it on.